# sin graphing trig reflection issue precalculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$-4\space \sin \space \left(-\frac{3\pi }{2}x+\frac{\pi }{5}\right)$$

When graphed out, the $x$-intercepts are $\displaystyle \frac{2}{5}$, $\displaystyle \frac{12}{15}$, and $\displaystyle \frac{22}{15}$ which I got. However, the graph is NOT reflected when I use a calculator

However, the function is clearly reflected (negative in front of the amplitude). Why is that?

Comment: try plotting without the $\frac{\pi}{5}$

Comment: how would that affect the reflection?

Comment: experiment with [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B%E2%88%924+sin+%28%E2%88%923%CF%80%2F2+x%29%2C%E2%88%924+sin+%28%E2%88%923%CF%80%2F2+x%2B%CF%80%2F5%29%7D ]

Answer (score 0):

Let's massage the equation a bit.

You have

$$y = -4 \sin \left(-\frac{3 \pi}{2}x + \frac{\pi}{5}\right).$$

Since the sine function is an odd function, $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x).$  So we can re-write your function as:

$$y = 4 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi}{2}x - \frac{\pi}{5}\right).$$

Now, $\pi /5$ is only $36^{\circ}$, which isn't that much of a phase shift.  Maybe this is why it looks like it's not reflected (inverted).